# how to access DOM elements using javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I want to get all the DOM elements that exist in a page through matching a JavaScript regex that matches the dom elements present on a page and returns the elements that contains this specific string: "tel:"

For example if an achor tag exists with `<a href="tel:+1222333458">1222333458</a>` the regex returns the DOM element.
or a span could contain this like : tel:
I have come up with a simple regex that matches the string "tel:"

```
/tel:*/g
```

but it does not do what I actually want it to do.

I am not just interested in anchor tags with href containing the "tel:" but any other dom element could contain tel: in any of their attributes or value or html using a javascript regex only
It should be able to find all elements where data attribute like this
data-mtype='tel:'

Comment: `/tel:*/` means `t`,`e`,`l` + zero or more `:`. So it will match the string `tel:::`. Remember, `*` means `zero or more of the previous character`. For example `a*` matches the empty string `""`, matches `a` matches `aaa` etc.

Comment: Is regex a requirement?  Are you inspecting just href attributes or anyplace within outerHTML?

Comment: Hey Juhana, I want a regex to match all the dom elements that contain atleast 1 time "tel:" and return me all those elements.

Comment: Hey JonSG, yes Regex is a requirement here,

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[href^="tel:"]')`

Comment: Hey  slebetman, I actually want the regex to fetch me all the dom elements that have "tel:" in any of their attributes of html or value just like this piece of code of javascript does: $("a[href^='tel:’]").each(function(){ });

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML.match(/([""])tel:.*?\1/g)`

Comment: https://github.com/kevinokerlund/dom-regex

Answer (score 1):

Updated it to show any element that contains `tel:`:

```js
console.log(
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function(element) {
    var match = element.outerHTML.match(/tel:/gi);
    if (match == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (match == void 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })
)
```

```html
<a href="1234 5678">1</a>
<a href="tel">2</a>
<a href="tel:1234 5678">3</a>
<a href="tel:12345678">4</a>
```

Comment: Hey, Emil S. Jørgensen! thanks for the reply, I am not just interested in anchor tags with href containing the "tel:" but any other dom element could contain tel: in any of their attributes or value or html using a javascript regex only.